# Xlsxwriter rotate image

Tags: image, insert, orientation, xlsxwriter

I am downloading a number of images to my local drive then adding them to a spreadsheet using insert_image(). The images are correctly oriented in Windows Explorer and other image viewing apps. However when I add an image (portrait) to the spreadsheet it becomes rotated to landscape. Landscape images do not appear to be rotated.

I also have a URL link for each image. When I click the image it opens up in a viewer in the correct orientation. It appears as if the insert_image is not respecting the image orientation. The EXIF information does not contain orientation.

Is there a way to specify image orientation, or rotate the image before inserting?

Thanks in advance,
Ian

Comment: There is no reason that XlsxWriter would  rotate an inserted image. It copies an image unmodified into the file format. If you post an example image I can have a look to see if anything unusual happens when handling it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. That does seem to be the behaviour. xlsxwriter insert images in the ‘raw’ orientation of the image.
I was trying to insert images which have exif information, where all image are captured in the same orientation - in supported viewers exif flag is used in to rotate the image to the way the camera was oriented when taking the photo. I have solved the problem by applying the rotation to the image before inserting it into excel using xlsxwriter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does Excel do when you insert an image with exif data set to rotate the image? Does it rotate it or insert it in raw format?

Comment: It appears to ignore the exif information and insert the image ‘as is’.